# Gradle script formatting

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, code-formatting

I'm trying to post some piece of gradle script at it doesn't look like code. Here it works:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
```

But on stackoverflow if look like regular text with indents:

[image]

Browser: 31.0.1650.57
System: OSX 10.9